# ¿Como conectar FTP y abrir archivo .txt?

Tags: php, mysql, ftp

Estoy tratando de conectarme a un ftp para abrir un archivo .txt necesito guardarla en una base de datos tengo el siguiente codigo pero no me funciona:

```
$archivo = fopen ("ftp://perez:perez12..@ftp.probando.com/u02/data/mensaje/SMS/SMS_WELCOME_CDR_20181108.txt", "r");
if (!$archivo) 
{
    echo "<p>No puedo abrir el archivo para lectura</p>";
    exit;
}

$texto="";
while ($linea = fgets($archivo,1024)) 
{
   if ($linea) $texto .= $linea;
}

echo $texto;
fclose ($archivo);
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
Warning: fopen(ftp://...@ftp.probando.vtr.cl/u02/data/mensaje/SMS/SMS_WELCOME_CDR_20181108.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Resource temporarily unavailable in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/web/perez/sistema/proceso.php on line 14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes usar ftp connect de php:

```
<?php

// definir algunas variables
$local_file = 'local.zip';
$server_file = 'server.zip';

// establecer una conexión básica
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// iniciar sesión con nombre de usuario y contraseña
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// intenta descargar $server_file y guardarlo en $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Se ha guardado satisfactoriamente en $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "Ha habido un problema\n";
}

// cerrar la conexión ftp
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

si deseas hacerlo por medio de sftp:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", 'r');
?>
```

fuente:
ftp
http://php.net/manual/es/function.ftp-get.php
sftp
http://php.net/manual/es/function.ssh2-sftp.php

Comment: Si entro por sftp puedo utilizar ese mismo codigo?